# Primeng not working correctly after adding Tailwindcss to Project

Tags: css, angular, typescript, tailwind-css, primeng

I tried to create a project using both tailwindcss and primeng. But after I import Tailwind, the styles of Primeng are not applied any further

I tried using the Tailwind prefix option, but as soon as I import Tailwind the styles of Primeng are not applied anymore.
To rule out other reasons, I created a fresh Angular project (Angular version 16) and installed only Tailwindcss and Primeng.

`tailwind.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
    prefix: "tw-",
}
```

`angular.json`

```
{
    "assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets"
],
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": []
},
```

`style.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";
```

In the app component I have a few test divs (Primeng button and Input - Tailwind container with some styles)

After I delete the tailwindcss imports (more precisely @tailwind/base) from the `style.css` the primeng components have the correct style. but the tailwind styles are lost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your style.css like this:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base" layer(tailwindcss);
@import "tailwindcss/components" layer(tailwindcss);
@import "tailwindcss/utilities" layer(tailwindcss);
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";
```

I tried and it's worked for me!

Comment: This is working fine for me, thanks man, you save my time :)

Answer (score 2):

add this into your tailwindcss.config.js :

```
corePlugins: { preflight: false }
```

I tried and did it

Answer (score 0):

Solutions already posted might work, however, PrimeNG has a reference for this subject in their documentation:

```css
@layer tailwind-base, primeng, tailwind-utilities;
        
@layer tailwind-base {
    @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
}
```

Doing this by reordering these layers will prevent tailwind preflight system to replace primeng styles

Source: https://primeng.org/guides/csslayer#tailwind

Answer (score 0):

After referring to the official documentation of the PrimeNG for [CSS Layers](https://primeng.org/guides/csslayer), I did the following changes to my **styles.css** file and it works for me.

```
@layer tailwind-base, primeng, tailwind-utilities;
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";

@layer tailwind-base {
  @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
}
```